# Google Custom Search layout problems

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

When I install the custom search script on my page, the layout is broken. See the attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I cut and pasted the following code:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '000119385509173658979:1gb8nobc8-a';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
```

It works but it looks screwed up. How can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the CSS that fixed it:

`.gsc-input-box {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
}`

.gsc-search-box .gsc-input>input:hover,
.gsc-input-box-hover {
  border: none !important;
}

.gsc-search-box .gsc-input>input:focus,
.gsc-input-box-focus {
  border: none !important;
}

.gsc-result .gs-title {
     line-height: 1.5em !important;
}

input.gsc-input {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9 !important;
}